# How to click programmatically on "Display images below" in Gmail using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, gmail, jquery-events

I am creating a Google Chrome extension that adds a keyboard shortcut for the link "Display images below" in Gmail using jQuery.

I have tried the following to simulate the click unsuccessfully:

```
$("#canvas_frame").contents().find("span:contains(Display images below)").mousedown().mouseup().click();
$("#canvas_frame").contents().find("span:contains(Display images below)").click();
$("#canvas_frame").contents().find("span:contains(Display images below)").mousedown();
$("#canvas_frame").contents().find("span:contains(Display images below)").mouseup();
$("#canvas_frame").contents().find("span:contains(Display images below)").trigger('click');
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
$("#canvas_frame span:contains(Display images below)")[0].dispatchEvent(event);
```

*Note: don't forget that GMail is **multilingual**, you may need a better method of selecting the element!*

Comment: I was able to get it to work thanks to your answer. Thank you. However, I changed the code as follows: var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
$("#canvas_frame").contents().find("span:contains(Display images below)")[1].dispatchEvent(event);

Comment: Yep I wasn't sure about the selector, because I couldn't find an email with image in my mailbox :)