# Automatically click “Display images below” in GMail

Tags: jquery, image, gmail

In this thread, I found code to automatically click on the "display images" button in GMail:

[How to click programmatically on "Display images below" in Gmail using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987155/how-to-click-programmatically-on-display-images-below-in-gmail-using-jquery)

However I couldn't use it. Could anyone please point me to a tutorial on how to implement this code to GMail on my Windows 7 x64 machine?

I basically just want GMail to always display all images in messages - no matter whom they come from!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this problem has been solved by a recent GMail update.

Now you can select this option in the GMail options (cogwheel on top right) by default and no coding is necessary!

Just in case someone stumbles upon this query!